# Can this simple Makefile support cross-compilation?

Tags: makefile

I have a very simple Makefile:

```
override CFLAGS+=-Wall -g
OBJS=myobj.o

all: mymain

mymain: $(OBJS)

myobj.o: myheader1.h myheader2.h
```

It works perfectly on a target system, but can I somehow pass it some arguments to not compile with `gcc` but with `mypreferred-gcc`?

Or I have to introduce some extra `CC` parameters and I have to build the compilation line in the Makefile to do this?

Comment: Run `make CC=mypreferred-gcc`

Comment: If you want to know what the default rules are (and the variables that are used to implement them) you can run `make -p -f/dev/null`.

Comment: I feel shame I couldn't find this by myself. Thank you